# How do I ngen .NET DLLs that are installed on my system to avoid JIT optimization for debugging?

Tags: .net, debugging, jit, ngen

I have the .NET Framework 4.0 installed and need to ngen a native image of a DLL from 3.5 without optimizations so I can debug it easier.

I've tried a couple of different ways:

1. Going to my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0`

Creating `System.Workflow.Activities.ini` with:

`ngen.exe uninstall System.Core.dll`

```ini
[.NET Framework Debugging Control] 
GenerateTrackingInfo=1 
AllowOptimize=0
```

and running

```
ngen.exe uninstall System.Workflow.Activities.dll
ngen.exe install System.Workflow.Activities.dll /Debug
```

Now, when I go to `C:\Windows\Assembly`, I see that the version installed is the MSIL, instead of AMD64.

2. I also tried going to `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL` and running NGEN there.

Again, no go.

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try GAC. You can do this on the CMD or the Visual Studio Command.

```
gacutil -if [DLLNAME.dll]
```

here is a bit more information: http://www.extofer.com/2011/03/visual-studio-external-gac-tool.html

Comment: Be *extremely* careful using GACUTIL. The implications are very very bad if you don't know what you are doing. If you run GACUTIL against your own assemblies, you MUST set references for your own DLLs to require specific version. If you do not and you install multiple versions of your software on your machine, you are likely going to have the wrong DLLs execute as the first port of call in search path is the GAC, not local assembly directory and it will just use the first one it finds on name match. It won't even check if the DLL is x86 or x64. It'll just grab the first one.